# how to handle multiple records in graphql django update mutation

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, graphql, typegraphql

The below method updates single emp record , how to handle the same for multiple emp recs at the same time.

```
{
(id : 1, firstName : "John", lastName: "Snow"),
(id : 2, firstName : "Tryrion", lastName: "Lannister")
(id : 3, firstName : "Jammie", lastName: "Lannister")
}
```

I am new to django and graphql kindly help me with code and query for the same

```
class UpdateEmp(graphene.Mutation):
    emp = graphene.Field(EmployeeType)

class Arguments:
    id = graphene.Int(required=True)
    first_name = graphene.String()
    last_name = graphene.String()

@login_required
def mutate(self, info,**kwargs):
    emp = Employee.objects.get(id=kwargs.get('id'))
    emp.first_name=kwargs.get('first_name')
    emp.last_name=kwargs.get('last_name')
    emp.save()
    return UpdateEmp(emp=emp)
```

graphql

```
mutation{
  uopdatemp(id : 1, firstName : "john", lastName: "Snow")
  {
    Employee{
      id
      firstName,
      lastName
    }
    
  }

}
```

Comment: I have optimize the answer a bit please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update multiple objects you need to define a new type and accordingly update your code like this:

**types.py**

```
class InputType(graphene.ObjectType):
    id = graphene.Int(required=True)
    first_name = graphene.String()
    last_name = graphene.String()
```

**mutation.py**

```
class UpdateEmp(graphene.Mutation):
    emps = graphene.List(EmployeeType)

class Arguments:
    input_type = graphene.List(InputType)

@login_required
def mutate(self, info, objs):
    emp_list = [Employee.objects.filter(id=obj.pop('id')).update(**obj) for obj in objs]
    return UpdateEmp(emps=emp_list)
```

**query:**

```
mutation{
  uopdatemp(input_type: [{id: 1, firstName: "John", lastName: "Snow"}, {id: 2, firstName: "Tryrion", lastName: "Lannister"}])
  {
    Employee{
      id
      firstName,
      lastName
    }
    
  }

}
```